# Django regex pattern for URL involving ?q= search query not working

Tags: python, regex, django, model-view-controller, django-views

I have a Django app which serves as a search tool. The problem I am facing is I cannot get the search results page working via `urls.py`

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    new_results = []
    error = True
    if "q" in request.GET: 
        query = request.GET["q"].strip()
        results = graph_search.main(query)
        for result in results:
            result[3] = result[3].decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
            new_results.append(result)
        new_results = list(reversed(sorted(new_results, key=itemgetter(4))))
        return render(request, 'search.html',
                      {'results': new_results, 'query': query})
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'error': error})
```

**urls.py**

**Rendering index.html**  - *Works fine*
`url(r'^$', 'searchengine.views.index', name='home'),`

**Rendering search.html** - *Works fine*
`url(r'^search', 'searchengine.views.search', name='search'),`

**Rendering search results** - *Does not work, instead renders index page*

`url(r'^/?q=<query>$', 'searchengine.views.search', name='search'),`

Can someone help me find the right regex pattern that I need to use in Django to render a url like `http://foo.com/?q=emily`

Piece of code for rendering search results in `search.html`

```
<p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if results %}
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="timeline-centered">
        {% for result in results %}
             <article class="timeline-entry">
                <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div class="timeline-icon bg-info">
                        <i class="entypo-feather"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-label">
                        <strong>Statement: </strong>{{ result.3 }}<br>
                        <strong>Doc: </strong>{{ result.0 }} <br>
                        <strong>Context: </strong>{{ result.1 }} <br>
                        <strong>Related: </strong>{{ result.2 }} <br>
                        <strong>Confidence: </strong>{{ result.4}} &#37 <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

{% else %}
    <p>No results matched your search criteria.</p>
```

The only way I can get it working is to change

`url(r'^$', 'searchengine.views.index', name='home')`

to

`url(r'^$', 'searchengine.views.search', name='search')`

But this makes the landing page render the search page instead of home page which is wrong.

Comment: should it be `?q=` instead of `?p=` in urls.py ?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso yes it is! that was a typo

Comment: I think it should be a back slash to escape the question mark in your regex, `^\?q=<query>$` or possibly `^/\?q=<query>$`. I'm not familiar with python though so could be wrong.

Comment: @chris85 I have tried them both. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looked at the doc, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/, so maybe it'd be `^\?q=(.*?(?:&|$))`. If not I'm not sure I'll leave it to someone with experience.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't capture the querystring in the URL patterns. Leave it off and access it via `request.GET['q']` in the view.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on this. How do you access it via `request.GET['q']` exactly.

Comment: I don't knew what else to tell you. Use that code in the view, it will give you the value of the `q` parameter.

Comment: I am already doing that in my view. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" isn't very useful - what exactly is happening? What error do you get?

Comment: It redirects to the index page instead of showing the results. In my return statement `return render(request, 'search.html',
                      {'results': new_results, 'q': q})` I am passing the `q`. The only way I can get the results displayed is by changing the `url(r'^$', 'searchengine.views.index', name='home')` to `url(r'^$', 'searchengine.views.search', name='search')` which again changes the home page to search page since it is the root url.

Comment: Well, yes. You can only have one view associated with a pattern. You need to deal with this in your home view, or use a different URL for your search view.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have problems about the capturing the query param.

```
url(r'^/?q=<query>$', 'searchengine.views.search', name='search'),
```

`?q=<query>` probably causes the problem.

Try following:

```
 url(r'^\?q=(?P<query_search>\w+)$', 'searchengine.views.search', name='search'),
```

Do not use `/` after `^` and escape `?` since it is a regex literal. Also using name groups (`?P<query_search>\w+)`) allows you to pass captured part to your view with the given parameter name. You can change capture criteria by changing `\w+`

*But on the other hand*, capturing a `GET` parameter in urls is not the right way yo go. See @DanielRoseman's answer for doing this within the view